# redundancy server for Apache /server failure/overload

Tags: apache, crash, redundancy

i want to create this scenario (or other recommended solution)

I want to have 3 running instances on amazon EC2 (3 different servers)

1. database (MySQL)
2. my web application (uses instance 1 as its db)
3. mirror application of 2 (also uses instance 1 as its db)

I want that a user that goes to my domain http://www.xxx.com will go to instance 2 as default action.

In case server 2 is down or overloaded it will automatically redirect to the mirror application (3)

how can i achieve such functionality ?

Comment: Usually you would have a Load balancer in front of your webservers to point in the right direction

Comment: and the load balancer is always online ?